# Making a copy of an Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers

I create two mutable arrays - referenceArray & stemArray, I then fill the referenceArray with URLs. I'd like to make stemArray an exact copy of referenceArray. I gather that making
the assignment stemArray = referenceArray; is not correct (strange things happen when I try this). There must be a better way then simply creating a second loop & filling up stemArray that way? I'm still not very comfortable with pointers & I believe this situation is a potential minefield...any hints or suggestions? thanks in advance :)

```
    referenceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfStems];
    referenceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    stemArray =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfStems];
    stemArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for ( int i = 1; i <= numStems; i++ ) {
    NSString *soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stem-%i", i];
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFile = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundPath];   
    [referenceArray addObject:soundFile];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting pointers to your mutable arrays immediately after you create them - why are those `alloc`/`init` lines in there?  If you want a copy of an NSArray, just send it a `copy` message:

```
referenceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfStems];

for ( int i = 1; i <= numStems; i++ ) {
    // Fill in referenceArray
}

stemArray = [referenceArray copy];
```

Comment: My program wouldn't run correctly without the alloc/init lines (eventhough this was technically wrong it worked in this case) - what i needed was 
ReferenceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfStems];
Thanks for the help, the 'copy' message was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Why couldn't you just alloc & init `stemArray` after you populate `referenceArray`?

Do something like this:

`stemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: referenceArray];`

Also, get rid of the DOUBLE alloc's you're doing there (i.e. the `arrayWithCapacity` lines).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here.  Let's walk through the existing code step-by-step:

```
// You are making a new mutable array that has a starting capacity of numberOfStems and assigning it to the referenceArray variable
referenceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfStems];

// You then create another new mutable array with the default capacity and re-assign the referenceArray variable.  Fortunately, the first array was created with -arrayWithCapacity: instead of -init...; thus, you aren't leaking an object
referenceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Same as above
stemArray =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfStems];
stemArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for ( int i = 1; i <= numStems; i++ ) {
    // This part looks fine
    NSString *soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stem-%i", i];
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFile = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundPath];   
    [referenceArray addObject:soundFile];

    // If you are in ARC, you are fine.  If non-ARC, you are leaking soundFile and need to do:
    // [soundFile release];
}
```

Based on your original description, you probably want to move the stemArray declaration to the end and use -copy or -mutableCopy:

```
stemArray = [referenceArray mutableCopy];  // If stemArray is defined as an NSMutableArray
```

or:

```
stemArray = [referenceArray copy];  // If stemArray is defined as an NSArray
```